# JQuery - how to addclass() to an element where it matches an attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a group of links for sorting, eg. category, name, date and have another group for Ascending / Descending. Initially when the page loads, none of these will be selected and the results will not be in any order.    When a selection is made, I need to have values for both groups ie. sortby and sortorder.

For example if a user selects sort by "category", the below function will use ASC as the default sort direction.  I then also need to be able to highlight the link with data-option-value="asc" by adding the class 'selected' to the link.

Can anyone assist?

```
        $('.sort a').click(function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);

            // Turn 'selected' class on/off
            if ($this.hasClass('selected'))
                return false;
            $this.parents('.sort-set').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');

            if($('.sortKey a.selected').attr('data-option-value')){
                key = $('.sortKey a.selected').attr('data-option-value');
            } else {
                 var key = 'date';
                 //.addClass('selected');  HOW TO DO THIS??
            }

            if($('.sortOrder a.selected').attr('data-option-value')){
                order = $('.sortOrder a.selected').attr('data-option-value');
            } else {
              var order = "asc";  
              //.addClass('selected');  HOW TO DO THIS??
            }

            $container.isotope({sortBy: valBy, sortAscending: valAscending});

            return false;
          });

                    <div class="option-combo sort">
                        <ul class="sort sort-set clearfix sortKey">
                            <li><a href="#" data-option-value="name">Name</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-option-value="category">Category</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-option-value="date">Expiry Date</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option-combo sort">
                        <ul class="sort sort-set clearfix sortOrder">
                            <li><a href="#" data-option-value="asc">Ascending</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-option-value="desc">Descending</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute value in the selector:

```
$("element[attribute='value']").addClass('selected')
```

Based on your comments it looks like you might need to do something like this:

```
$("a[data-option-value='asc']", ".sortOrder").addClass('selected')
```

Comment: You're query is redundant... You're getting the links with the 'selected' class and adding the 'selected' class? This wouldn't appear to have any affect, as the returned elements would already have the class.

    $(".sortKey a[data-option-value='date']").addClass('selected')

Comment: What Im trying to do is check to see what link has the class  'selected'. Then based on what what group the link is in, I need to add a class 'selected' to another link.  Not the same link.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Im not very good with Jquery syntax, I imaging its somethinglike this: $(".sortOrder:has[data-option-value='asc']").addClass('selected');

Comment: It kindof does. Your query will only add a class to the link return, though. You probably need to do that in multiple lines and build a selector. I'll update the solution with some details so the code is formatted.